# PHP getElementById returns null

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to use getElementById on a XML document inside using PHP.

PHP Code is:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->validateOnParse = TRUE;
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents( <DocumentPath> ));
var_dump($dom->getElementById('rect1'));
```

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rectangles xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="XML-DOM-RectSchema.xsd">

<rectangle id="rect1">
    <innerText>Rectangle 1</innerText>
    <bgcolor>black</bgcolor>
    <fontcolor>white</fontcolor>
    <height>50</height>
    <width>100</width>
    <timespan>2002-05-30T09:30:10Z</timespan>
</rectangle>
```

XSD Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="rectangles">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="rectangle" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="innerText" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name="bgcolor" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name="fontcolor" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name="height" type="xsd:positiveInteger" />
                        <xsd:element name="width" type="xsd:positiveInteger" />
                        <xsd:element name="timespan" type="xsd:dateTime" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID" use="required" />
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

I can't understand why var_dump prints "NULL", whereas when I try var_dump($dom) it prints the right stuff, so the document is correctly loaded.
Obviously XML and Schema are well-formed.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the xsd schema declaration?

Comment: No changes, always NULL

Comment: It's not the first time when getElementById does not work. I use $xpath = new domXpath($dom); var_dump($xpath->query('//*[@id="rect1"]'));

Answer (score 0):

$dom must be an reference to one object in the DOM document input, edittext, label's and other objects.